# Do I need a 301 Redirect after clean URL's

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I've just been through the process of cleaning my URL's

Original Dirty URL :- `http://www.michelledaniels.co.uk/photos/index.php?/page/contact-michelle`

New clean url :- `http://www.michelledaniels.co.uk/photos/page/contact-michelle`

Should I now set up a 301 redirect to avoid duplicate content issues?

Many thanks for your help?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you do need 301 redirects from old URLs to new ones in order to avoid duplicate content.

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(photos)/index\.php\?([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$ 
RewriteRule ^(photos)/(.+?)/?$ /$1/index.php?$2 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thanks but that didn't work , my host one.com doesnt support multiviews.

Comment: You can comment out Options line.